# Fetch two columns from database and present as a single array

Tags: php, arrays, postgresql, cakephp-2.0

I have a postgres table and I am interested in extracting two columns (longitude, latitude) from this table using Cakephp and presenting them as a single array that I will pass to a maps data layer to display markers on a map.

what I have tried to do

```
   $coordinateData = $this->FieldVisit->find('all', [
                'contain' => [
                    'FieldVisit'
                ],
                'fields' => [
                    'longitude',
                    'latitude'
                    ]
                ]);
            $dataArr = [];
            foreach ($coordinateData as $data) {
                $dataArr[] = $data[0]['longitude'];
                $dataArr[] = $data[0]['latitude'];
            }
```

Comment: Explain properly what you want ?

Comment: Thank you @ahmad for the cool edit on the code

Answer (score 0):

please try with this statement

$dataArr = Set::extract($coordinateData, '{n}.FieldVisit');